# Что с пассивной подпиской на события?

Tags: javascript, события, кроссбраузерность

Обнаружил интересную фичу - подписку на события с указанием [`passsive: true`](http://caniuse.com/#search=passive), что должно позволить браузеру оптимизировать стандратные действия, т. к. мы таким образом обещаем не отменять их.

С точки зрения логики это дополнительная плюшка, которая не должна ничего портить в случае, если браузер её не поддерживает. Но есть одно жирное НО.

В классическом варианте подписка осуществлялась одним из этих способов:

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener);
target.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
```

Теперь же надо в третий параметр [запихнуть объект](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-addeventlisteneroptions-passive):

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener, {useCapture, passive, once});
```

Тут есть ещё и once, у которого [поддержка ещё хуже](http://caniuse.com/#search=once).

Какие проблемы могут возникнуть, если передать объект в качестве последнего параметра, когда браузер не поддерживает passive?

Следующий код в IE11 выдаёт 1, т. е. capturing, а в хроме 3 - bubbling. Логично ли рассчитывать, что объект будет рассматриваться как true, что означает, что если я подписываюсь на capturing-стадию и не использую `once`, то всё будет работать одинаково?

Или есть другие варианты, например исключение?

https://jsfiddle.net/5o88hq7u/1/

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener(
  'click',
  function(e) { alert(e.eventPhase) },
  { passive: true }
);
```

```html
<div><button>Click me</button></div>
```